# Malloc memory to char * in function. Return *char or pass char ** as function parameter?

Tags: c, malloc

```
char *a = NULL;
char *b = NULL;
```

**Method 1:**

```
char *malloc_string(int string_size){
    return (char*)malloc(string_size);
}

a=malloc_string(4);

free(a);
```

**Method 2:**

```
void malloc_string(char **a, int string_size){
    *a = (char*)malloc(string_size);
}

malloc_string(&b, 4);

free(b);
```

Which would you choose and why?

Comment: It's up to you. Both methods are correct.

Comment: BTW don't cast the return value of malloc in C, so actually the first method is useless, just use `a = malloc(4)` instead of `a = malloc_string(4)`

Comment: A common reason for using the pattern in method 2 is for the function to return an error code, rather than being `void`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither: both are terrible.

1. Don't have stub functions for `malloc` since your code becomes less clear to folk reading your code. (`malloc` is a standard function and everyone knows what it does.)
2. And don't cast `malloc` on the right hand side of `=`: it's bad programming style since (i) you are repeating yourself and (ii) someone refactoring your code might change the pointer type in one and not the other place. That can introduce undefined behaviour.

Comment: So, malloc within a callable function is bad? You mean you would malloc for pointer first and then pass the pointer to function?

Comment: No that's fine. But I'd never stub `malloc` for the sake of it. Just don't lose track of the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer *this* question, **TL;DR**, any one. Both are OK.

To nitpick, NONE, because

1. Both the methods lack error check. What's the use of the wrapper then?

   1.1. If I pass `string_size` as a -ve value, `malloc()` will blow up.

   1.2. `malloc()` failure (or, success) should be checked before using the returned pointer.
2. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Thanks! Of course in practice, I will add checks on parms, this piece of code is just to describe the question briefly.

Comment: @AttufliX That's why I mentioned my statements in "nitpick". :-)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in C would be to never define an `malloc_string()` in the first place, it just introduces an unnecessary (and, hopefully optimized-away) function call. Just do this:

```
a = malloc(4);
```

See also [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Apart from that, your argument type is wrong, it must be `size_t`, not `int` (and your compiler should warn you about this, enable compiler warnings)

Finally, you should probably define a *single* wrapper around `malloc` to handle errors in a central place ... in it's simplest form, it would look like this:

```
void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ret;
    if (!(ret = malloc(size))
    {
        /* perror("malloc"); */
        exit(1);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You are right, malloc receives size_t params. I think enabling compiler warnings is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is worth substituting is free(), the C standard doesn't say that after freeing the memory the pointer has to be NULLed;

```
#define SAFE_FREE(m)    \
{                       \
   if(m)                \
   {                    \
      free(m);          \
      m = NULL;         \
   }                    \
}
```

A good practice is to NULL the freed pointer, that will help to catch potential problems earlier aspesially if you have a habit to use assert for every internal functions, like this:

```
void foo_internal(void* p)
{
   assert(p != NULL);

   // ...
}
```

If you do not NULL the pointer after freeing it and call the func the assert will never be triggered on the most compilers and platforms (memory allocation are platform specific).

That might seem not a big deal if you have IDE debugger and can step through the code but in some cases, like UEFI, embedded, etc. where you don't have a debugger that simple practice would save a lot of headache!

Comment: Yeah, not properly free the pointer or use an already freed pointer may cause many headache problems. Setting NULL to freed yet pointer and using assert is really a good habit. Tks!